# Exercises on Galois Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, galois-theory, book-recommendation, online-resources

I need a source for exercises on classical Galois Theory, or to be more specific, Galois extensions of finite fields and the rationals as well as applications (solvability by radicals, for example).
So far, I have worked with Tignol's "Galois Theory of Algebraic Equations". Any additional suggestions would be appreciated, whether it is a textbook or a website, but the language should be English. Solutions are welcome, but no necessity.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I really like the exercises in [Lang's *Algebra*](http://books.google.com/books/about/Algebra.html?id=Fge-BwqhqIYC). There's a little bit of everything in there.

[Milne's notes](http://jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ft.html) have exercises at the end of every chapter, a chapter of review exercises, and a two-hour exam; solutions (or at least hints) for all of these are given at the end. A lot of the action takes place over $\mathbf Q$, but I saw a fair number of questions about finite fields and they seemed good.

[Keith Conrad's handouts](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/) don't have a lot of exercises, but when I had to review this stuff I found it helpful to look at the statements of his examples, try them for myself, and then read his methods. There are usually myriad ways to solve exercises in this area.

Teruyoshi Yoshida has fun [example sheets](http://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~ty245/2010_Galois_M24/2010_Galois_M24.html), in addition to complete course notes.

Comment: Thanks to you, too; I wanted to get Lang's book as a reference, but I'll take a look at the exercises as well.

Comment: No problem! Lang's book is divisive, but it can teach you a lot, and the field theory chapters are probably its best; [George Bergman's companion to the book](http://math.berkeley.edu/~gbergman/.C.to.L/index.html) could be useful as well.

Answer (score 8):

Try these books:

- [Classical Galois Theory with Examples](http://bookstore.ams.org/chel-268/)
- [Exploratory Galois Theory](http://ebooks.cambridge.org/ebook.jsf?bid=CBO9780511755200)
- [Galois Theory for Beginners: A Historical Perspective](http://bookstore.ams.org/stml-35)

Comment: Thanks, I will check them out as soon as possible.

Answer (score 3):

Many pages of exercises at J K Verma's website, [here](http://www.math.iitb.ac.in/~jkv/algebra2/prob.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried working through:

(I) Abstract Algebra by Dummit & Foote

(II) Field and Galois Theory by Patrick Morandi

Both of these books are rich with exercise problems and the questions are very diverse. I would recommend you to go through these, as they helped me tremendously.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the fairly recent [Galois Theory Through Exercises](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-72326-6) by Brzezinski. (See [here](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/galois-theory-through-exercises) for MAA review.)