# Galois group of $X^4+4X^3+12X^2+24X+24$

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory

What is the best method to find the Galois group of $P = X^4+4X^3+12X^2+24X+24$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ ?

First, I don't manage to show that $P$ is irreducible : Eisenstein doesn't work.

I know that its discriminant is a square, so, if we assume that $P$ is irreducible, $Gal(P, \mathbb{Q}) \subset A_4$. But if we reduce $P$ modulo $2$ or $3$, we don't obtain something interesting (I think).

Comment: To show it is irreducible (over $\Bbb Q$) prove it doesn't have any rational roots and that it can't be the product of two polynomials of degree $2$ by solving a system.

Comment: Really, solving a system ? There is no a quicker method ?

Comment: I forgot to mention that it's better if you use the above with the second [Gauss's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss's_lemma_(polynomial)). Also remember you can suppose the two polynomials are monic. If you want you can even go $\pmod p$.

Comment: There might be some linear substitution that works, but the simpler ones don't work and others I wouldn't really classify them as 'faster'.

Comment: Ok thank you. So, assume that I've done it. How to compute the Galois group now ?

Comment: Do you know the method by Dedekind-Frobenius? Also consult http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220310/tips-for-finding-the-galois-group-of-a-given-polynomial

Comment: No, I don't know it. I just follow an introductory Galois Theory course.