# Galois Theory Texts

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, galois-theory, book-recommendation

What is a very comprehensive text regarding Galois Theory?

I'm about to take a course in Galois Theory this spring, and I usually like to complement my course texts with something more rigorous, such as Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis* or Ahlfor's *Complex Analysis* for my real/complex analysis courses, that way I can continue my learning even after a semester without skipping a beat.

I've heard of Lang's Algebra book, and it certainly seems to be good in terms of Algebra, but I wasn't sure how it stacked up when it came to Galois Theory. What say you, MSE?

Comment: You might want to peruse these recent notes [*An Introduction to Galois Theory by
Andrew Baker*](http://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/~ajb/dvi-ps/Galois.pdf), including the nice list of references in the bibliography. Regards

Comment: @Amzoti: Thanks for the link! I'll definitely give it an in-depth consideration when I have more time (probably tomorrow morning).

Comment: @Amzoti Nice link, looks like they were just updated. Thanks.

Comment: [Stewart - Galois Theory](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Galois-Theory-Third-Chapman-Mathematics/dp/1584883936) is a great introductory text. I found it very useful when I took a first course in Galois Theory last year. It's not the most comprehensive though. Hope that helps!

Comment: I taught from the 2nd edition of Stewart several times. I wasn't happy with the changes in the 3rd edition, but it's still not a bad book for your purposes.

Comment: Here is a link to another generously free download from Milne. I have not used this, but his texts are excellent. http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ft.html

Comment: Also "Dummit & Foote" is excellent with lots of examples and detailed proofs.

Comment: For a different perspective, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/53661/589

Answer (score 2):

Hungerford's book *Algebra* has excellent coverage of lots of topics, including Galois theory.  It also has an excellent selection of problems. It is a good place for a first run through the subject, before you read something more specialized.

The 1984 book by H. M. Edwards looks like a a good choice for further study.