# Recommended Field and Galois Theory Books

Tags: reference-request, galois-theory, extension-field, book-recommendation

I'm studyding Field and Galois Theory and I need to practice doing exercise, to or to be more specific, algebraic extension, normal extension, ...
Can someone represent a book of this kind with (many) exercises and solutions to do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Dummit and Foote / Hungerford

Comment: Ian Stewart - one of the best maths authors ever.

Comment: You might have a look at other questions tagged [galois-theory+book-recommendation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/galois-theory+book-recommendation). In the sidebar among related questions this one was listed: [Exercises on Galois Theory](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/53658). Perhaps it might be also interesting for you.

Comment: I've been using [Milne](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/FT.pdf) and enjoying it well enough.