# Expository Books for Galois Theory

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, field-theory, galois-theory

I'm looking into studying Galois Theory and potentially doing some undergraduate research within the field.  What are some texts one would recommend for the subject.

Thank you.

Comment: Lang's *Algebra* has an exposition of the theory as well as a host of useful problems

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/152824/589 and https://math.stackexchange.com/a/53661/589.

Answer (score 6):

I know it is not a "big name", but Ian Stewart's *Galois Theory* served me well. I went into the class with some linear algebra and group theory, and came out with a good grasp of Galois Theory and some of its famous consequences.

A really nice feature is that he reaps some benefits of the theory before it is fully explained. Like after he explains the degree of a field extension, he then does some non-constructability proofs (one example: he shows that you can't trisect an angle of $\pi /3$ radians with a compass and straight-edge.) I'm not sure if this is standard, but it gives you a sense of satisfaction early on.

Also the introductory chapters are historically rich in a way I haven't seen before.

Comment: And the multiple choice questions at the end of each chapter are also very helpful. Nice book, recommended!

Comment: It can be found here: http://math.illinoisstate.edu/schebol/teaching/407-14-files/Stewart-galois_theory.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Emil Artin's ***Lectures on Galois Theory***.   The best there is.  Only $82$ pages.  Try it, you'll love it!

Comment: Though I disagree with this as an introductory text, after you go through the subject this is a great reference. Also the [Dover edition](https://www.amazon.com/Galois-Theory-Delivered-University-Mathematical/dp/0486623424/) is cheap as beans. It belongs on every mathematician's shelf.